# How to draw heart shape (3D) using Maple

Tags: maple

I'm drawing a heart shape (3D) using Maple, but I think it is not correct. Please hint to me how to draw it correctly.

> with(plots);
>
> implicitplot3d((2*x^2+y^2+z^2-1)^3-(1/10)*x^2*z^2-y^2*z^3, x = -1.2 .. 1.2, y = -1.2 .. 1.2, z = -1.2 .. 1.3, numpoints = 80000);

[image]

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't questions about 3D heart shapes belong in medical-imaging or something?

Comment: What's not correct about it? Do you not like the actual heart or the way that Maple plots it? Do you think something is wrong with Maple's plot?

Comment: In fact,I want to know whether it is correct or not?

Comment: I suppose "correctness" is a matter of taste. Does it look like a heart shape to you?

Comment: $\Large\color{red}{+1}$ nice question

Comment: $\ddot\smile+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with(plots);

implicitplot3d((2*x^2+y^2+z^2-1)^3-(1/10)*x^2*z^2-y^2*z^3, x = -1.2 .. 1.2,
                 y = -1.2 .. 1.2, z = -1.2 .. 1.3, numpoints = 80000);
```

it is true. no problem in plot.